# Xamarin ContentPage.ToolbarItems after navigationService.NavigateAsync("/Login"); disappear

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, prism, toolbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAMBm.jpg)
MainPage ToolBar:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Text="My Sos Requests" Command="{Binding GoToMySosRequests}" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Secondary" Text="Logout" Command="{Binding Logout}" Priority="1"  />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

MainViewModel:

```
Logout = new BitDelegateCommand(async () =>
{
await securityService.Logout();
await navigationService.NavigateAsync("/Login");
});
```

LoginViewModel:

```
await securityService.LoginWithCredentials(UserName, Password, "Owner", "secret");
await navigationService.NavigateAsync("/Main");
```

App Class:

```
public App() : base(null)
{
   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView());
}
```

Also ContentPages have a title attribute.

When I click "LogOut" and Login again the ToolbarItems disappear in MainPage.
When I remove / (slash) before "/Login" or "/Main" , problem resolves.
But I don't want user can back to before page after login or after logout.
What should I do?

Comment: Would you mind provide a demo?

Comment: resolved : await navigationService.NavigateAsync("Navigation/Main");